# I have an error: 504 Gateway Timeout with envoy and openiddict

Tags: envoyproxy, openiddict

When I run my project (openiddict) without envoy, its fine, but when I implement openiddict with envoy, it ran into this error: 504 Gateway Timeout: upstream request timeout

Here is my envoy.yaml:

```
admin:
 access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
 address:
  socket_address:
    protocol: TCP
    address: 0.0.0.0
    port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
   address:
      socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 10000
  filter_chains:
   - filters:
     - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
       typed_config:
         "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter
            .network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
        stat_prefix: ingress_http
        route_config:
         name: local_route
         virtual_hosts:
        - name: local_service
          domains: ["*"]
          routes:
          - match:
              prefix: "/a"
            route:
              prefix_rewrite: "/api"
              cluster: api_service
      http_filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.http.router
clusters:
 - name: api_service
   connect_timeout: 0.25s
   type: LOGICAL_DNS
   dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
   lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
   load_assignment:
     cluster_name: api_service
     endpoints:
     - lb_endpoints:
       - endpoint:
          address:
            socket_address:
              address: api
              port_value: 80
```

How do I set time out for my api? how to fix this? Anyone get an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timeout in the `route` configuration section (see `timeout` attribute):

```yaml
routes:
- match:
    prefix: "/a"
    route:
      prefix_rewrite: "/api"
      cluster: api_service
      timeout: 60s
```

From the [docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.1/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-config-route-v3-routeaction-timeout):

> If not specified, the default is 15s.

Also:

> A value of 0 will disable the route's timeout.

Note that if you want to disable the route's timeout, you will have to set `timeout: 0s` and **not** `timeout: 0`.